# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Enemy.Update ()(at Assets/Scripts/Enemy.cs:30) как решить ошибку в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Помогите, пожалуйста, со скриптом для врага. Ошибка в 30 строке:
`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Enemy.Update ()(at Assets/Scripts/Enemy.cs:30)`

Скрипт Enemy:

```
    using UnityEngine;     
    using UnityEngine.AI;

    public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
    {
    
    public GameObject player;
    NavMeshAgent agent;       
    Animator anim;
    public float dist;
    public float Radius = 15;

    public int health = 3;

    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        dist = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, player.transform.position);
        if(dist > Radius)
        {
            anim.SetBool("Run Forward", false);
            agent.enabled = false;
        }
        if(dist < Radius)
        {
            agent.enabled = true; // 30 строка
            agent.SetDestination(player.transform.position);
            anim.SetBool("RunForward", true);
        }
        if(health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("pamagite");
        }
    }
    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        health -= damage;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Вряд ли ошибка именно на той строке, которую вы указали (вы в вопросе указали на `if (other.gameObject = "Enemy").`). Потому что при входе объекта в триггер - Юнити 100% гарантированно на вход подаёт именно тот самый объект

Comment: а вот тут `agent.enabled = true` объект `agent` не определён. Он `null`. Отсюда и ошибка. Нужно в него добавить инициализацию....т.е. в поле `NavMeshAgent agent;` надо чтобы что-то было

Comment: Спасибо! Постараюсь исправить!

Comment: А в чём именно загвоздка? что вы делаете и что не получается?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Проблема**
Как вы и указали, в строке `agent.enabled = true;`
В данном случае вы предполагаете, что в переменной `agent` находится какое-то значение типа NavMeshAgent, однако на самом деле она оказывается пустой, а точнее равной [`null`](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.26.php)

**Решение**
Вам следует инициализировать переменную agent изначальным значением. Например, если компонент NavMeshAgent висит на том же объекте, что и скрипт Enemy (скорее всего, так и есть), то переменную `agent` вы можете инициализировать в методе `Start` вместе с `anim` через [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html):

```
void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}
```

!> P.S. Из комментариев: `Жаль что я глупый, проблему все еще не могу решить(` - подобные комментарии на ruSO не приветствуются. Вам следует пытаться разобраться в проблеме, а не прятаться за щитом неумения, чтобы проблему решили за вас.

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь буду знать!